# How to detect rowspan greater than 1 from copy paste event clipboard data?

Tags: javascript, html, excel, events, frontend

I'm trying to build a feature in my web app which allows users to copy paste a table from another website and it would populate the table in my web app with the pasted data. I want it to work the same way it does on Excel. However, I'm not sure how to handle the case if a cell has a rowspan that is greater than 1.

I am currently splitting the pasted data through the newline character and the tab character.

```
    const clipboardData = e.clipboardData || e.originalEvent.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
    const pastedData = clipboardData.getData("text");
    const pastedTable = [];
    pastedData.split("\n").forEach((rowStr) => {
      const rowArr = rowStr.split("\t");
      pastedTable.push(rowArr);
    });
```

When all cells in the website have a rowspan = 1, this works fine, populating every cell into a 2D array (rows x columns). However, if there are cells with rowspan > 1, it doesn't quite get it right.

[image: Example]

[image]

**TLDR**, I want to know whether there is some delimiter that allows me to detect a cell with rowspan > 1. When I copy paste this table into Excel, the Excel cells were populated correctly. The cell with the "First Half" and "Second Half" text were merged appropriately as well. If Excel was able to detect the cell with rowspan > 1, I assume there must be a way to detect this from the clipboard data from the paste event?

Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks.